# Insert specific values of object into mongodb using nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am using nodejs for server side connection, I got json object which i posted below, i want to insert that json into mongo based on certain conditions

This is my json:

```
"_id" : ObjectId("5a1507f7c6e9dc046ee76b01"),
    "sendStatus" : false,
    "draftName" : "ifelse",
    "draftData" : {
        "sms" : {
            "message" : "Sample",
            "sender" : "ifelse"
        },
        "contacts" : [
            {
                "selected" : true,
                "updatedAt" : "2017-11-18T06:17:32.000Z",
                "createdAt" : "2017-11-18T06:17:32.000Z",
                "data3" : "",
                "data2" : "",
                "data1" : "",
                "country" : "",
                "url" : "",
                "company" : "",
                "email" : "sameer@gmail.com",
                "dob" : null,
                "postcode" : "",
                "region" : "",
                "city" : "hhhh",
                "street" : "Salai",
                "lastName" : "Sameer",
                "firstName" : "Mohamed",
                "gsm" : "122,
                "id" : 1
            },
            {
                "selected" : true,
                "updatedAt" : "2017-11-18T06:17:57.000Z",
                "createdAt" : "2017-11-18T06:17:57.000Z",
                "data3" : "",
                "data2" : "",
                "data1" : "",
                "country" : "",
                "url" : "",
                "company" : "",
                "email" : "ham@gmail.com",
                "dob" : null,
                "postcode" : "",
                "region" : "",
                "city" : "",
                "street" : "",
                "lastName" : "Basha",
                "firstName" : "Hameed",
                "gsm" : "123450987",
                "id" : 2
            },
            {
                "selected" : true,
                "updatedAt" : "2017-11-22T04:32:09.000Z",
                "createdAt" : "2017-11-22T04:32:09.000Z",
                "data3" : "",
                "data2" : "",
                "data1" : "",
                "country" : "",
                "url" : "",
                "company" : "",
                "email" : "gane@gane.com",
                "dob" : null,
                "postcode" : "",
                "region" : "",
                "city" : "",
                "street" : "",
                "lastName" : "Pandiyan",
                "firstName" : "Ganesh",
                "gsm" : "213",
                "id" : 3
            }
        ]
    },
    "draftType" : "",
    "createdOn" : ISODate("2017-11-22T05:15:35.423Z"),
    "updatedOn" : ISODate("2017-11-22T05:15:35.423Z"),
    "__v" : 0
```

I am inserting this data into mongodb, but i want to set one condition,

i want to insert only contacts:[{selected:true}], which having keys as selected:true, if object key is selected:false, i dont want to insert that data into mongodb, Help me.

This is my backend code:

```
exports.addContactDraft = function (req, res) {
    console.log('contactttttttttt', req.body);
    var newContactDraft = req.body;
    newContactDraft.createdOn = new Date();
    newContactDraft.updatedOn = new Date();
    new Draft(newContactDraft).save(function (err, data) {
        if (err) console.log('new  err:', err);
        else res.status(200).send(data);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you only want to filter out the elements from contacts. You can easily filter out unneeded objects from contacts array with array.filter().

Checkout the below code.

```
var data = {your json object stuff....}
 //Filter out the contacts with 'selected=false'

 data.draftData.contacts = 
data.draftData.contacts.filter(contact=>contact.selected===true);

//Modified contacts that include only the objects with selected property equal to true.

console.log(data);
```